# How to find this angle?

Tags: geometry

$P$ is a point in $\triangle ABC$. If $\angle PAB = 10^\circ$, $\angle PBA = 20^\circ$, $\angle PAC = 40^\circ$ and $\angle PCA = 30^\circ$, find $\angle B$.

Comment: Any thought about the problem?

Comment: you can understand my answer?????please tell.

Comment: @krishan Frankly speaking, its very difficult for anyone to understand who you write with the poor formatting.

Comment: swarnik!please edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\angle PBC=x$. so for the condition $\angle PCB=80^\circ-x$.

- Apply "trigonometric expression of ceva's theorem"-$ \frac{\sin 10^\circ}{\sin 40^\circ}\times  \frac{\sin x}{\sin 20^\circ}\times \frac{\sin 30^\circ}{\sin(80^\circ-x)} =1$
- From that we have $\frac{\sin x}{\sin(80^\circ-x)}=4\cos 10^\circ \sin 40^\circ=4\cos 10^\circ\cos 50^\circ=2(\cos 60^\circ+\cos 40^\circ)=1+2\cos 40^\circ$
- Now see .........$\sin 60^\circ-\sin 20^\circ=2\cos 40^\circ\sin 20^\circ$. from this equation we have  $1+2\cos 40^\circ=\frac{\sin 60^\circ}{\sin 20^\circ}=\frac{\sin x}{\sin(80^\circ-x)}$. so comparing we can say $x=60^\circ$
- so $\angle B=20^\circ+60^\circ=80^\circ$.
  -